# Java how to have two variables point to the same primitive object

Tags: java, pointers, variables

I am writing a platform game in Java in which there are various game objects such as platforms, the player, and (eventually) enemies.  I describe the position of these game objects with rectangles:  x position, y position, width, and height.  However, I would also like to add in other variables to describe the position:  left, top, right, and bottom.  For the last two I know I will need to change them whenever x, y, width, or height gets modified, but as left and top are the same as x and y, I was wondering how I could get them to point to the same value as x and y.  I think this can be done in C with the #define function, but sadly this is Java, not C.

How can I get two different variable names to point to the same value in Java such that if one changes, the other changes as well?

Edit:  Here is the basics of my GameObject class:

```
 public abstract class GameObject {
    protected float x;
    protected float y;

    protected float right;
    protected float bottom;
    protected float width;
    protected float height;

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
        right=this.x+width;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
        bottom=this.y+height;
    }
    //A bunch of other getters/setters

    //Subclasses must have render (for displaying graphics) and tick (mainly for updating position) functions.
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);

    public abstract void tick();
}
```

What I would like to do is add in two more variables:

```
protected float left = x;
protected float top = y;
```

and have these refer to the same primitive as x and y (not copy the primitives).  This, apparently, does not seem possible.  Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done in Java in the sense that you mean it.  You can have two object references that point to the same object, but if you have a normal primitive variable, those are always distinct and don't refer to each other.  You can *make* an object to hold a primitive, have two different references to that same object, and a change to the contents of that object through one reference will be reflected in the other, but you *cannot* have an `int x` and and `int y` where writing `x = 10` will make `y == 10`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need something behaving like a reference to a primitive, you need to create an object holding that primitive value and then share the "holder" object.

However, I don't think this is the best way to tackle your problem.

As I understand your game objects, they can be entirely described with `x`, `y`, `height` and `width` variable. `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` on the other hand, are values that can derived from the four basic ones.

In fact, it would be possible to have a game object containing only `x`, `y`, `height` and `width` and to compute the other four values outside of the object whenever they are needed. Such an object could look like this :

```
public class GameObject {
  private int x, y, height, width;

  public int getX() { return x; }
  public int getY() { return y; }
  public int getHeight() { return height; }
  public int getWidth() { return width; }

  public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
  public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
  public void setHeight(int height) { this.height = height; }
  public void setwidth(int width) { this.width = width; }
}
```

Notice that the actual variables are `private` and only readable through getters. This helps to avoid the use of a variable reference later on.

Now, to have an easy and unique way to access to `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom`, while you *could* add four variables and keep them in sync with the four other variable already present, I think it is not the best way to do it.

I suggest that you just compute them on the fly inside slightly smarter-than-average getters. It would look like that :

```
public class GameObject {
  // getters and setters omitted for brevity
  private int x, y, height, width;

  public int getLeft() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getRight() {
    // assuming x increase toward the right
    return x + width;
  }

  public int getTop() {
    return y
  }

  public int getBottom() {
    // assuming y increase toward the bottom
    return y + height;
  }
}
```

This will also help if you need to create some special update methods, like `moveRight(int delta)`, `scale(double factor)` since you will only need to apply changes to the basic variables and not the values that are derived from them.

Answer (score 0):

int/integer is passed by value, not by reference in java.

You can define a new class, For example,

```
public class Position {
     int x;
     int y;
}
```

Let two variables point to the same instance of Position.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by creating a new Class. Java is object-oriented, so, basically, everything is about classes and it's instances. Take a look at an example below:

```
class GameObject
{
     //Instance variables
     //(all objects of this class will have their own)
     int x;
     int y;
     int width;
     int height;

     //Constructor
     //(you call a constructor when creating a new object)
     GameObject(int x, int y, int width, int height)
     {
          //Here you are assigning the values received to the instance variables (marked with "this", that represents the current object)
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
     }

    //This method will return the ordinate ("y") of the object's top position (assuming the "y axis" points down)
    int getTop() {
        return (y - height/2);
    }
}
```

After creating the class **GameObject**, you can create instances (objects) of it. Look below:

```
GameObject player = new GameObject(0, 0, 50, 50); //creates a new object with coordinates (0,0), width = 50 and height = 50
GameObject enemy1 = new GameObject(30, 50, 100, 100);

//Getting the "x" position of the player and the monster
System.out.println("Player X = " + player.x);
System.out.println("Enemy1 X = " + enemy1.x);

//Get the top position "y" 
System.out.println("Player top = " + player.getTop());

//Change player's "y"
player.y = 10;

//Get player's top position again
System.out.println("Player top = " + player.getTop()); //it will have changed, since "y" was changed.
```

Oracle has a really good lesson about *Object-Oriented Programming*, you should check it out [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html). The C language is structured, while Java is Object-Oriented, these are two different paradigms. I hope this was of help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In java there are two types of variables.
1.Primitive types
2.Reference types

You need to use reference type variable if you want to refer the same object through different variables.

In your case for gaming application those parameters might change frequently.
So **if all the time values**, left and top are **same** as x and y, you can use use one variable to represent the both parameters which saves memory.
e.g : for left and x use one variable.

Or else using java OOP concepts,
you can make those x, y, left, top parameters private and assign getters and setters for those.

```
public int setX(int x){
    this.x =x;
}

public setLeft(int left){
    this.left = left;
}

public int setY(int y){
    this.y =y;
}

public setTop(int top){
    this.top= top;
}

public setXnLeft(int xnleft){
    setX(xnleft);
    setleft(xnleft);
}

public setYnTop(int yntop){
    setY(yntop);
    setTop(yntop);
}
```